# $L_2$ norm and an improper integral as a limit

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $f\in L_2(R)$ then:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty|f(x)|^2dx=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{-2^n}^{2^n}|f(x)|^2dx
$$

**Questions:**

1) Why is it possible to go from an improper integral to a limit of a sequence of regular integrals? Does it have something to do with $f$ being from $L_2(R)$?

2) Why the following estimate is correct:
$$
\forall\epsilon>0 \quad \exists N \quad s.t. \|f(x)-f_{(N)}(x)\|_{L_2(R)}<\epsilon
$$
where
$$
  f_{(N)}=\left\{
  \begin{array}{@{}ll@{}}
    f(x), & \text{if}\ |x|\leq2^N \\
    0, & \text{if}\ |x|>2^N
  \end{array}\right.
$$

Thank you for your help!

Comment: For 1) Apply monotone convergence theorem, or dominated convergence theorem: they both work.

Comment: @Dr.MV technically this is not the definition.  For example, $\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{-2^n}^{2^n} x\,dx$ exists, but the improper integral diverges.

Comment: Also, if one is working in $L^2$, one has to use the Lebesgue integral. The monotone convergence theorem and the fact that $ f $ is summable if and only if $|f|$ is for the Lebesgue integral implies there isn't really such a thing as an "improper" Lebesgue integral.

Comment: The word 'improper' is a legacy of Riemann. In the definition of Riemann integral, a finite interval is needed for the formulation of Riemann sum. Then one understands the integration on infinite intervals as limit of those on finite intervals. But in the definition of Lebesgue integral, one in fact starts with functions on the whole domain which is $(-\infty,\infty)$ in our case. Thus the improper integral in the sense of Riemann is maybe the most proper in the sense of Lebesgue.

Comment: @omnomnomnom The definition of an improper Riemann integral - with unbounded integration limits - is the limit $\lim_{L\to \infty}\int_a^L f(x)\,dx$.  The integral either converges or doesn't.  I'm uncertain as to the meaning of your comment.

Comment: @chappers One can work in $L^2$ with improper Riemann integrals.  There was an extensive set of comments on a question asked yesterday as to the meaning of an improper Lebesgue integral.  For example, $\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(x)}{x}\,dx$ doesn't exist as a Lebesgue integral, but does as an improper Riemann integral.  So, why not use Lebesgue and evaluate the limit $\lim_{L\to \infty}\int_0^L \frac{\sin(x)}{x}\,dx$ and call it an improper Lebesgue integral.  The comments became mildly heated.  I wasn't involved, until the end I wrote "Gentlemen you can't fight in here.  This is the war room.

Comment: @Dr.MV Well, there are functions in $L^2$ that are not Riemann-integrable. And the whole point of $L^2$ is that is composed of measurable functions that are absolutely square-integrable, so in this case, the integral of the absolute value exists anyway, and if the improper Riemann integral exists, it is of course equal to the Lebesgue integral in such a case. [...]

Comment: [...] If one actually wants a non-absolute integral which includes the improper Riemann integrable and the Lebesgue integrable functions, one can always use the Henstock–Kurzweil integral. Absolute integrals tend to behave better, just as absolutely convergent series do: the H–K theory of Fourier integrals is pretty grim, if I remember correctly.

Comment: @Dr.MV there is a difference between saying that $\lim_{x \to -\infty,y \to  \infty} \int_x^y f(x)\,dx$ exists and saying that $\lim_{x \to \infty} \int_{-x}^x f(x)\,dx$ exists.  The former is the definition of an improper integral.  The latter is that which is encapsulated by the sequence in question.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I didn't say any such thing.  I said $\lim_{L\to \infty}\int_a^L f(x)\,dx$.  The lower limit is finite.  And I certainly know the difference between a CPV and an improper integral $\lim_{M\to \infty, L\to \infty}\int_{-M}^L f(x)\,dx$.  With that said, the integral in the OP is indeed a CPV one.

Comment: @Chappers Yes, of course.  There are functions that are $L^2$ in the sense of improper Riemann integrals.  And yes, there are obviously functions that are $L^2$ as Lebesgue integrals that are not RI even in the improper sense and even in the sense of CPV.

Comment: @Dr.MV Well, you answered *"Why is it possible to go from an improper integral to a limit of a sequence of regular integrals?"* by saying *"That is the definition of an improper integral"*, which is overly reductive.  Hence, I said "technically, that not the definition"; there are subtleties that need to be addressed, and glossing over them is not helpful for someone just learning about $L_p$ spaces for the first time.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom And I just acknowledged that the integral in the OP is a CPV.  And I've deleted my initial comment.

Comment: @Dr.MV okay, glad we're on the same page.  Sorry for all the hassle.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom No apology necessary.  I posted a comment which could be misleading.  Glad you alerted me to it.  -Mark